# In R, why wont system.time work in a loop?

Tags: r, time

I want to measure how long things take to sum and compare how the number of things to add changes the time. For example, I want to  see the time for when there are 1, 2 or 3 numbers to sum.

```
for (j in 1:3)
  print(j)
  user_time <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))[1]
  print(user_time)
```

I expected to get output like below:

```
> for (j in 1:3)
+   print(j)
[1] 1
>   user_time <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))[1]
>   print(user_time)
user.self 
        0 #or some  other time
+   print(j)
[1] 2
>   user_time <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))[1]
>   print(user_time)
user.self 
        0 #or some  other time
+   print(j)
[1] 3
>   user_time <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))[1]
>   print(user_time)
user.self 
        0 #or some  other time
```

But instead I actually got:

```
> for (j in 1:3)
+   print(j)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
>   user_time <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))[1]
>   print(user_time)
user.self 
        0
```

The system time only seems to run on the last iteration of the loop.

How can I get the user time for each different test?

Comment: You need braces around the body of your for loop.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-writing `user_time` at each iteration. Make a list instead and append the values during your loop. Next you can compare times or sum them as you prefer

```
user_time <- list()
for (j in 1:3) {
...
user_time[[(length(user_time) + 1)]] <- system.time(my_sum_func(j))
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Paul's comment of adding the braces made the time display each iteration of the loop.  Damiano, thanks for such a complete solution, (the way you used length + 1 for indexing solved the next thing on my to do list of jumping more than 1)  Thanks to you both.